# Display list item as a pop-up

Tags: list-view

I'm moving content from and old inactive SharePoint Online to a new Share Point Online with the morden experience.

I have a list where emails with a daily reports are saved. There is a flow that copy the email content to the list.

The problem occur when we now try to open the list item in the new page. On the old page, when clicking on the list item is the item opened in a centered pop-up like this. I don't know how this works since it was created before my time at the company:

[image: Old view]

In my new list on the modern site is the item opened at the right of the screen (default way) which leads to that only half the message is visible like this (the problem is marked in red):

[image: New view]

Is there a way to make the entire email visible or bring back the pop-up behavior?

Comment: There is a list setting -> advanced setting - > Open items in new Dialog, which used to work in classic view.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is the difference from "classic" to "modern".

Simply switch the List back to classic mode to have the old layout back. Check [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/196286/7045) on how that works.